# Properties.Settings.Default.Save() does not save

Tags: c#, settings

[Found several related articles but none had a resolution that fixed it for me.]

I'm trying to store user-selected options between sessions of running the program.  All attempts to use `Properties.Settings.Default.Save()` have no impact; changing a setting value is not persisted between sessions of the installed program.  No exception is caught in the `SettingsSave()` method.

```
private void SettingsLoad()
{
    SettingsLoad(this);
}

private void SettingsSave()
{
    try
    {
        SettingsSave(this);
        MessageBox.Show("Values written successfully", "Saved");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       MessageBox.Show(Utility.ParseException(ex), "EXCEPTION!");
    }
}
....

public static void SettingsLoad(object main)
{
    foreach (SettingsProperty setting in Properties.Settings.Default.Properties)
    {
        // Attempt to get a reference to the property and, if found, set its value
        var prop = main.GetType().GetProperty(setting.Name);
        if (prop != null)
        {
            prop.SetValue(main, setting.DefaultValue);
        }
    }
}

public static void SettingsSave(object main)
{
    foreach (SettingsProperty setting in Properties.Settings.Default.Properties)
    {
        // Attempt to get a reference to the property and, if found, update its value
        var prop = main.GetType().GetProperty(setting.Name);
        if (prop != null)
        {
            setting.DefaultValue = prop.GetValue(main).ToString();
        }
    }
    // This line has no impact; changes are not persisted
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find your code a bit confusing.

To read a property:

```
string val = Properties.Settings.Default.Property_Name;
```

To write a property:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Property_Name = val;
```

To save all properties:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save
```

Property values will be restored next time you run the program.

Comment: I had already tried explicit assignment in SettingsSave() and Properties.Settings.Default.Save() still failed.  But I found that by also using explicit assignment in the SettingsLoad(), then this began working and I then saw the user.config file appear under AppData\<assembly_name>.  Going to investigate why the method of driving off the list of properties still fails.  And that user.config mechanism is pretty ugly.. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Important note ! Please note **Application scope settings are READ ONLY**. You can update only user scope settings. This info is not readily available in documentation or buried deep.